# How to get payment using virtual account number in Flutterwave

Tags: flutterwave

I use v3 API to create virtual account in Flutterwave for my customer.

This is api document: https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference/create-a-virtual-account-number-1

The following is my POST JSON data in this API:

```
{
    "email": "test@flutterwave.com",
    "is_permanent": true,
    "bvn": "12345678901",
    "tx_ref": "",
    "phonenumber": "",
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "narration": ""
}
```

I get following  response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Virtual account created",
  "data": {
    "response_code": "02",
    "response_message": "Transaction in progress",
    "order_ref": "URF_1642326884898_5501535",
    "account_number": "1234567890",
    "bank_name": "TEST BANK",
    "amount": "NaN"
  }
}
```

Now I could not understood that suppose I need to get 1000 NGN payment from customer using this virtual account then which API should I need to use as per v3 API docs ? Because when I have created virtual account then I did not used amount.

And so now to get payment of 1000 NGN, which API should I need to call with 1000 NGN ? I know that I will get notification in webhook, but when he will do payment then and then I can get notification. I did not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call any API to receive fund into your virtual account. Simple initiate a transfer using USSD, Internet Banking or Mobile app to that account number.